# Asynchronous call to server being blocked by bluetooth LE Scan

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I have an `Activity` which constructs a `RESTManager` class (used to make an asynchronous call to the server and return data to the `Activity`).

However, after I construct my `RESTManager` and call the server using

```
        //Retrieve data from server
        RESTManager m = new RESTManager(this,getApplicationContext());
        //Set the data list
        m.delegate=this;
        m.retrieveRoomData();
```

the server call does **not** go through until I turn **off** bluetooth scanning.

However, I start my bluetooth scan immediately after the `RESTManager` as such:

```
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(100l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(100l);

    //Set the custom BeaconLayout for iBeacons
    if (myPref.getBoolean("layoutSet", true)) {

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        Log.v("Beacon Layout", "Beacon Layout Set");
        myPref.edit().putBoolean("layoutSet", false).apply();
        myPref.edit().commit();
    }
    beaconManager.bind(this);
```

I am not getting any error.

Is there any reason why my AsyncTask from RESTManager would hang from the bluetooth scans?

Relevant code:

RESTManager class

```
    public class RESTManager {
    private DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.now();
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
    private ArrayList<RoomData> roomDataList = new ArrayList<RoomData>();
    private ArrayList<MeetingData> meetingDataList = new ArrayList<MeetingData>();
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private Context context;

    public RESTManager(Activity currentActivity, Context context) {
        this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        this.context = context;
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    //Todo update meeting data logic
    public ArrayList<MeetingData> retrieveMeetingDataFromServer() {

        return null;
    }

    public void retrieveRoomData() {
        new CallServerForRoomData().execute();
    }

    //TODO add timestamping logic.
    private class CallServerForRoomData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String myJsonData = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //If the data isn't cached, call the server.
            if (!mPrefs.contains("RoomData")) {
                try {
                    setupHttpClient();
                    HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient(RequestMethod.GET, "http://10.184.46.217:9012/v1/rooms", new HttpHeaders(), null, null);
                    myClient.connect();
                    HttpResponse mR = myClient.processResponse();
                    myJsonData = mR.getServerResponseAsString();
                    System.out.println(myJsonData);

                    preferenceEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                    preferenceEditor.putString("RoomData", myJsonData);
                    preferenceEditor.commit();
                    setRoomDataList(convertRoomDataJson(myJsonData));
                    return "server";
                } catch (HttpClientException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //If it is cached, retrieve the data locally.
            else {
                setRoomDataList(convertRoomDataJson(mPrefs.getString("RoomData", "NULL")));
                return "local";
            }

            return "Done";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            delegate.dataFinishedRetrieving(getRoomDataList());
            // setRoomDataList(convertRoomDataJson(myJsonData));
            currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data retrieved on " + result + " storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * AsyncTask for retrieving a room's meeting data.
     * Pass in the room's unique identifier as a parameter of the execute method.
     */
    //TODO add timestamping logic
    private class CallServerForMeetingData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String myJsonData = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                setupHttpClient();
                HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient(RequestMethod.GET, "http://10.184.146.217:9012/v1/room/" + params[0] + "/schedule", new HttpHeaders(), null, null);
                myClient.connect();
                HttpResponse mR = myClient.processResponse();
                myJsonData = mR.getServerResponseAsString();


            } catch (HttpClientException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Set the converted MeetingData to the RoomData object
            for (RoomData e : roomDataList) {
                if (e.getObjectId() == params[0]) {
                    e.setMeetingData(convertMeetingDataJson(myJsonData));
                }
            }

            return "Done";
        }
    }

    //Initializes the HTTPClient and attaches it to the application lifecycle.
    public void setupHttpClient() {
        HttpCacheManager.init(Application.getAppContext());
    }

    public ArrayList<MeetingData> convertMeetingDataJson(String JsonData) {
        final Gson gson = initCustomGSON();
        Type MeetingDataListType = null;
        if (JsonData != "") {
            MeetingDataListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MeetingData>>() {
            }.getType();
        }
        return (gson.fromJson(JsonData, MeetingDataListType));
    }

    public ArrayList<RoomData> convertRoomDataJson(String JsonData) {
        final Gson gson = initCustomGSON();
        Type RoomDataListType = null;
        if (!JsonData.equals("")) {
            RoomDataListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<RoomData>>() {
            }.getType();
            roomDataList = (gson.fromJson(JsonData, RoomDataListType));
        }
        roomDataList = (gson.fromJson(JsonData, RoomDataListType));
        for (RoomData e : roomDataList) {
            Log.v("RoomData name", e.getName());
            Log.v("RoomData roomId", e.getObjectId());
            //Log.v("RoomData imageUrl", e.getImageUrl());
            if (e.getBeacons() != null) {
                Log.v("Number of beacons", e.getBeacons().toString());
            }
        }
        return roomDataList;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the GSON Json Decoder with the custom JodaTime serializers.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Gson initCustomGSON() {
        final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        JodaTimeConverters converter = new JodaTimeConverters();
        converter.registerAll(builder);
        return builder.create();
    }

    public ArrayList<RoomData> getRoomDataList() {
        return roomDataList;
    }

    public void setRoomDataList(ArrayList<RoomData> roomDataList) {
        this.roomDataList = roomDataList;
    }

    public void setMeetingDataListForRoom(RoomData whichRoom) {
        new CallServerForMeetingData().execute(whichRoom.getObjectId());
    }
 }
```

Comment: which is the device you are testing this on, it may be because the wifi would lose connection or the internet connection through wifi and bluetooth are affected when run simultaneously

Comment: Moto X 1st Generation (2013).

Comment: It works fine on my Nexus 9. Not sure why the Moto X is blocking.

Comment: have seen serious issues on MotoG , it could be the native stacks, just observe what happens to the wifi signal strength when you enable and disable the bluetooth, from the settings, without your app

Comment: My signal strength doesn't drop. But it locks the AsyncTask from ever being executed.